# не подхватывает ~/.bashrc

Tags: linux, bash

Если коротко, есть vds, при подключении к ней по ssh я захожу из-под root

Я поменял `~/` для root с `/root` на `/home/root`

Но теперь у меня автоматически не подхватывается `/home/root/.bashrc` и мне каждый раз при прдключении надо писать `source ~/.bashrc`

Как это исправить?

Comment: а шел вызывается у вас как `sh` или `bash` ? [смотри раздел - Invoked by remote shell daemon](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files)